# Checking String within A String For a Directory: Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to move files from a submissions directory into individual student directories for grading.  Below is a screenshot of the script I am trying to use to do this:

[image]

My issue is that the if condition does not evaluate to true, even though I know for certain the name variable is contained within the submission file.

Here is an example of `line` and `name`:

`line: submissions/saundersjacob_hw4.pl`
`name: jacob`

Since 'jacob' is contained within the string 'submissions/saundersjacob_hw4.pl', I wish it to return true, but it does not. Can someone assist me with this?

Please disregard the lines containing `echo` and my pseudo unimplemented move line after the if statement.

Kind regards,

Comment: Please do not post images of text or code. Please post code as text into the question.

Comment: try `[[ "$var" == *"$name}* ]]`

Comment: Bash regex works, too: `if [[ "${line}" =~ .*"${name}".* ]]; then echo found; fi;`

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Jevon's answer has worked.  Will post code next time, apologies for not doing so in this context.

Answer (score 1):

From bash manual https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html :

> [[…]]
>
> ```
>  [[ expression ]]
> ```
>
> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string **to the right** of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching, [...]

Not the string to the left. You can match the left with the pattern on the right, not the other way round.